# Double-clicking on Office 2010 shortcut only opens in minimized mode, not full screen

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2010

After installing Office Home and Business 2010, I doubled clicked on the Word icon (I created shortcuts for all Office applications). I expected it to open up in fullscreen view.

However, it opens up in minimized mode and just sits in the taskbar.  I tried to right-click to open a document or even close the program but it just sits there.  The only way to get Word off the taskbar is to reboot.

No problems with Excel, Powerpoint, etc.  When I double-clicked on other applications in the Office suite, they open right up.  It is just the Word program which is giving me problems.  I have installed all available updates.

Answer (score 1):

Can you check if you open Word from Run prompt, the problem still occurs?

1. Press Windows Key + R.
2. Type Winword.exe

Also double click the Word shortcut you created. Open task manager and try to kill it.To open task manager:

1. Right click on the task bar. Click "Start Task Manager".

EDIT 1:
I searched around in google and found this KB article for the said problem. Basically the screen X Y co-ordinates for Word may be corrupt.

See article:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/264299